# Sequence in mongo - can rely on findAndModify()?

Tags: java, mongodb, sequence

I need some persistence integer Id for an operation called about 100 times a second. I have a single document in Settings collection where id is stored in lastId field.

As per [mongodb doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify) I want to implement it using `findAnyModify()` operation with `update: { $inc: { lastId: 1 } }` parameter. Can I rely on that each next call returns a new (incremented) number?

Or is it better as a workaround to use java `AtomicLong` counter? It will read `lastId` from mongo on start, and on each increment I will write (but not read) from mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a persisted sequence in mongodb, you indeed need to use the operator [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) in order to increment atomically on server side a given field that you will use as counter.

If you use an `AtomicLong`, you will hardly be able to guarantee the consistency of your sequence (especially in cluster environment) such that you could face situations where you end up with the same id for several documents.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!